# XAML Itemscontrol binding to property outside of the control

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have a list of transactions that I am loading into an ItemsControl but I want to show the UserId from my viewmodel in each row/transaction. The userId is not in the transaction list, it's a property in the viewmodel I am trying to access but it seems everything I've tried doesn't work and I don't know why. All I get is a blank column value. (yes, I did confirm the property is not empty. even hardcoded a value and got nothing).

My understanding is I should be able to use the RelativeSource with an AncestorType of Window to access the property. Am I missing something?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyReportResult.Transactions}" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="20 2 0 2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 20 0" Text="{Binding Path=UserId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 20 0" Text="{Binding Path=Amount}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RelativeSource binding tries to find the property in the parent Window, although it is in the Window's DataContext.

The following should work, provided that the `UserId` property is in the same view model class as `MyReportResult`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.UserId,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
```

Comment: (facepalm) I never thought to use the AncestorType=ItemsControl. I was trying almost every other type than that, long night. Thanks @Clemens!

Answer (score 0):

Only WPF supports RelativeSource because it's not strictly necessary.  It's less fragile to use ElementName instead like so:

First, give an x:Name="something" to your top level object or its child (usually a Grid).

Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.UserId, Element=something}"